# Spring RequestMapping not working for a controller class method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Tomcat Logs:

```
Jun 15, 2014 4:55:50 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI[/test_mvc/service/countryservice/countrybycode/US] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
```

WEB.xml usrl mappings for dispatcher servlet :

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller Method is getCountryByCode in below controller class:

```
 @Controller
 public class CountryController {
 @Autowired
CountryDAOImpl countryService;

@RequestMapping(value="/service/countryservice/countrybycode/{code}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getCountryByCode(@PathVariable("code") String code){
    String country = null;
    if(code != null){
        try {
            country = countryService.getCountryByCode(code)  ;
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return country;         
}

@RequestMapping(value="/service/countryservice/countriesbycodes/{codes}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getCountryListByCodeList(@RequestParam("codes") List codeList){
    List<String> countryList = null;
    countryList = countryService.getCountriesByCodes(codeList);
    return countryList;     
}
```

Everything executes successfully no errors are observed on the console logs , as soon as i hit the url : http://`localhost`:9999/test_mvc/service/countryservice/countrybycode/US(this is a dummy URL posted here actual has a different Ip address) , i get 404 error and the log has the warning mentioned above.I suspect there is something related to url mapping that i am missing out here

Comment: Post the entire controller class.

Comment: Also Share your web.xml file

Comment: You have written two url pattern. . In the web.xml. so I am not sure how to map the requests. . If u want multiple requests to mappings use * . I think url pattern is the  issue.